# An upper bound for the number of answers of this equation

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $n$ be a natural number and $p$ a prime number less than or equal to $n$.

$$\begin{align}
n^2 + 2n &\equiv a \pmod p\\
n^2 + 1 &\equiv b \pmod p
\end{align}$$

If $a \lt b$, $p$ is an answer for the equation.

Is there an upper bound for the number of answers to this equation?

I checked some cases and guess for $n\ge k$, an upper bound for the number of answers is $\frac t2$.

Let $t$ be the number of primes less than or equal to $n$.

For example consider $n = 20$:

All prime numbers less than or equal to $20$ are $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19$

$$\begin{align}
20^2 + 2(20) &= 0 \pmod 2\\
20^2 + 1 &= 1 \pmod 2\\[5pt]
0 &< 1
\end{align}$$

…so $p=2$ is an answer of the equation.

Comment: By "number of answers", what do you mean? The question is very unclear in writing.

Comment: I just run a program which searches maximum values for $\frac{q}{\pi(n)}$ and the current maximum is $\frac{10}{13}$, so an upper bound could be : $\frac{10}{13}\pi(n)$. The maximum occured for $n=42$.

Comment: For large $n$, the bound $\frac{\pi(n)}{2}$ is not too bad.  Starting with $n=10,000$, I did not beat $\frac{653}{1288}\pi(n)<0.51\pi(n)$ yet. Maybe, we have $q$ ~ $\frac{\pi(n)}{2}$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: I do not think, I can.

Comment: For $n>10^5$, we seem to have values below $\frac{\pi(n)}{2}$.

Comment: It would be very interesting to calculate $$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{q(n)}{\pi(n)}$$ , where $q(n)$ is the answer for $n$

Comment: For $20\le n\le 60,000$, the inequality $\frac{3}{13}\le\frac{q(n)}{\pi(n)}\le \frac{10}{13}$ holds.